# Is it possible to set a default 'snippet' when creating a override function in VBnet?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function, inheritance

I've made a MustInherit Class with functions. When not implementing this function in a class that inherits this 'MustInherit Class', a potential fix shows up suggesting to implement an abstract class:

```
Public Overrides Sub Function_A()
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Sub
```

However, I would like to set a default 'code' inside this function. In case this function is added, a part of it is already filled in automatically.

```
Public Overrides Sub Function_A()
    Dim a As String = "Test" <-- Filled in automatically
    Dim b As Integer = 123 <-- Filled in automatically
End Sub
```

What I mean, is that when I type in a mustoverride or overridable function into a derived class, it does auto-complete with "Throw New NotImplementedException()" in it, but I would like to add my own example code into a function. Right now I am creating a template class file with a few overridable functions.

How could I create a custom default code for that auto completion?

Comment: [Code snippet functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippet-functions) => [Walkthrough: Create a code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet)

Comment: No, not possible. `a` and `b` are local variables in a method in the base class. You can't access them in a method override in a derived class and continue from there. If you need them in a derived class, then expose them by public, Friend, or Protected fields or properties. You can make the `Function_A` in the base class **Overridable** rather than **MustOverride** and call the base class version in the derived class to instantiate some objects and assign some values and continue from there.

Comment: What I mean, is that when I type in a mustoverride or overridable function into a derived class, it does auto-complete with "Throw New NotImplementedException()" in it, but I would like to add my own example code into a function. Right now I am creating a template class file with a few overridable functions. If a user types in a name of the function, Visual Studio autocompletes it with "Throw New NotImplementedException()" in the function. How could I create a custom default code for that auto completion?

Comment: ah, then I received it wrongly. See Jimi's links then.